# Use a ConstraintValidator to validate an object

Tags: validation, annotations

I want to run this past my fellow Java hacks.  See if this seems to be sane enough to you.  There may be a better way to do this but I was thinking: Can I write a dual-purpose ConstraintValidator that can validate a field (an object of some kind) as it is passed into a method and also be used to validate an instance of that object outside of that context while still using annotations?  I came up with the following approach.  Let me know what you think of it.  Use case:

```
...
@POST
public Response retrieveSomething(@Encoded @IsAParamValid MyParamObject myParamObject)
{
  ...
}
```

I also want to be able to do this somewhere else in code:

```
IsAParamValidValidator.validate(myParamObject);
```

without duplicating the logic to do the validation.  Critical here is I want the automatic exception-generating service that using @IsAParamValid in a method call gets me.

Answer (score 0):

My idea of a way to get the best of both worlds:

My annotation class:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {IsAParamValidValidator.class})
@Documented
public @interface IsAParamValid
{
 String message() default "The param was invalid";
 Class<?>[] groups() default {};
 Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

My validator class:

```
public class IsAParamValidValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IsAParamValid, MyParamObject>
{
  public static void validate(@IsAParamValid MyParamObject myParamObject) {
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(IsAParamValid isAParamValid) {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(MyParamObject myParamObject, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext)
  {
    // do the check
    boolean bResult = ... whatever ...
    return bResult;
  }

}
```

OK so what do you all think?

Comment: Scratch this... I don't get the automagical error-throwing when using it as a stand-alone validator.  Now... can anyone say HOW I might get that?